# GRUB on USB Pendrive Custom Entry Workaround

Tags: bash, grub

well, i had installed Porteus on a USB Pendrive i make it with 3 partitions, first partition on exFAT (For Old Windows Compatibility), second with ext2 because is the boot partition, and the third partition have the Porteus ISO & Data Folders.

You can see on this another post -> https://forum.porteus.org/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=10878&p=94752#p94752

Well the thing is inside my grub.conf i put this workaround

```
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sda2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sda3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sda4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sda5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sda6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sda7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sda8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd0,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sda9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd1,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdb9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd2,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdc9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd3,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdd9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sde1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sde2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sde3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sde4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sde5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sde6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sde7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sde8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd4,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sde9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd5,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdf9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd6,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdg9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd7,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdh9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd8,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdi9" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos1" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj1" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos2" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj2" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos3" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj3" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos4" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj4" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos5" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj5" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos6" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj6" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos7" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj7" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos8" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj8" ; fi
    if [ "$root" == "hd9,msdos9" ]; then unset root ; root="sdj9" ; fi
```

Someone can tell me if inside grub, this workaround can be more short like using a loop, array or another thing ?

with linux ever hd"number"(this number should be change to letter for example 0=a, 1=b, 2=c, . . .),msdos"number" this number is not change, just the "msdos" word is must not present anymore on this conversion.

i suppose grub are bash compatible (but with less commands) someone had idea how i can do this in a short lines, i really don't like repeat almost the same per line.

Comment: I have booted Ubuntu from flash drives. But flash drive that is sdc, becomes sda on reboot. Or if booting grub on sda, it may be hd1 or hd2. I typically just have one entry in grub to boot ISO, hdXY, and if it does not work, grub lets me go back and edit entry to different hdX. Partition Y never changes. Suggest in future to use gpt partiitons, not MBR(msdos).

Comment: The issue i had when i boot is sda but when porteus distros found it conf file change from sda to sdc then try to load modules from /mnt/sda3 but the path now should be /mnt/sdc3

Comment: Are you not able to edit grub.conf when booting to change both hdX,Y and any references to sda to sdc?

Comment: i can change some values temporally, but that does not work if i put this same pendrive on another pc and for example detect my usb pendrive on sdz i need a better workaround for make after found porteus conf file, search and mount the correct partition before the modules try to be loaded

Comment: Also UEFI allows you to select an external drive to boot, just like a live installer. That entry always is /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi. So you can always just boot from UEFI. Other systems may not be booting grub by default, if  Windows or SystemD boot, then you have to boot from UEFI boot menu, not grub.

Comment: My pc is too old, not have EFI/UEFI mode on the motherboard, i not use SystemD

Comment: BIOS also lets you select to boot an install in an external drive. Just tell it to boot sdc drive.

Comment: The popup menu just allow select a drive, not a partition. But the issue is reduce my work around to some more short and effective.

Comment: But if using BIOS, a drive choice is the only choice for booting. BIOS only boots from MBR of a drive and cannot directly boot a partition.

Comment: and then is there when i use grub on usb. well i had found a solution without using this workaround you can visit on url -> https://forum.porteus.org/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=10878&p=94752#p94752

Comment: You could try labels: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive

Comment: i can't use labels like that i need more points of something.